# Horizontal ListView Stacked

Tags: .net, windows, winrt-xaml

I am trying to create a UI look that is very similar to the People app in Windows 8. I want to have a horizontal stack of items, with Group separators.  I tried this with GridView and came close but ran into a problem where the first item rendered set the height for all items to follow.

I next tried the ListView, but I could get items to stack vertically and also flow horizontally.

Can anyone either assist me with this or point to where I might find source for the Windows 8 built in apps.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'horizontal stack of items', are you referring to the [`Panorama`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941104(v=vs.92).aspx) control?

Answer (score 0):

Does this cover it?  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/966aa897-1413-46f0-bef7-663de36f9423